# modify previous URL works but not on how i want it to work

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hello guy's and girls,

I am using `window.history.replaceState(null, null, 'products.php?searchText='+keywords);`. Which works great it adds the parameter search value to the URL but if i go to the previous page when parameters are inside the URL it doesn't work nice. I want it to go back to the products.php page if i go back with the browser button. Then i found this code below online. But this only works if i refresh the page and i am already on a parameter URL. Then it works. But it doesn't work if i add this to a `keydown/keyup` code.

My question is how this can be solved.

I tried to add a TimeOut on `keyup/keydown` but that also didn't work either obviously. I am out of ideas, i don't know what to do, can someone help me with this please.

I appreciate your time and effort.

```
var pageName = $('#pageName').attr('value');
//execute only if i am on the products.php page
if(pageName == 'products.php') {
//execute only if there is a parameter inside the URL
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('?searchText=') > 0) {
    history.pushState(null, null, '<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>');
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
        window.location.assign(document.location.protocol +"//"+ document.location.hostname + document.location.pathname);
          //for if it doesnt work for chrome iphone
          // window.location.href("http://www.yoururl.com/");
    });
  }
}
```

I am working with AJAX/Jquery btw for the search output to appear in the page.

Answer (score 0):

It works like below, now the previous page will be products.php after i entered search and parameters to URL:

```
var pageName = $('#pageName').attr('value');
if(pageName == 'products.php') {
  //REMOVED THIS ---> if (window.location.href.indexOf('?searchText=') > 0) {
    history.pushState(null, null, '<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>');
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
        window.location.assign(document.location.protocol +"//"+ document.location.hostname + document.location.pathname);
      });
  }
```